# How to Fetch data from webAPi using nodeJS libraries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to nodeJS, i want to fetch data from webApi using nodeJS, for instance, when i make a call to the

> mydomain/getAllStudents

i want all the students data and when i do

> mydomain/student/4

then i want only the data of the student with the **ID=2**

**-challenge-**

using express i can specify the route like this

```
var app=express();
app.get('/getAllStudents',(request,response)=>{    
console.log('we are listening !!!');
}).listen(8080);
```

but when i try to make a call inside the callback function, i not able to get the value, my complete code

```
var http=require('http');
var express=require('express');

var app=express();

 var options={host: '172.17.144.6',
  port: 8394,
  path: '/api/Masterdata/getAllStudents',
  method: 'GET'}

app.get('/getAllStudents',(request,response)=>{

http.get(options,(res)=>{
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
console.log('we are listening !!!');
}).listen(8080);
```

what i am trying to achieve is, when i hit **`mydomain/getAllStudents`** i want to get all the data. how can i do this with nodeJS? can i do this with nodeJS statisfying my requirement?

Comment: Change `request.get('172.17.144.6:8394/api/Masterdata/GetAllCountry');`
to
`request.get('/api/Masterdata/GetAllCountry');`

Not sure, but I believe that since you have already defined the url pattern(?) in the options, redefining it again will cause it creata url similar to 

`http://www.172.17.144.6:8394/172.17.144.6:8394/api/Masterdata/GetAllCountry`

Comment: please see my updated question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to expose the data through express after parsing them from another API.
You can do like this:

To make the call from node js you can use this library:
[node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client)

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var remoteURL = "172.17.144.6:8394/api/Masterdata/getAllStudents";

var express = require('express');
var students = express.Router();
students.route('/getAllStudents')
 .get(function(req, res) {
    client.get(remoteURL, function (data, response) {
     console.log(data);
    if(response.statusCode === 200)
      res.status(200).send(data);
    });
});
```